# Compare output of “DOS” command to something

Tags: batch-file, ms-dos

(by DOS I mean windows cmd.exe - I don't want to enforce powershell or similar on the end user)

I want to run a command line file that prints output to CON / the screen.

I want to capture that output and compare it to an expected output.

... in a .bat / .cmd file?

---

Specifically, the [`identify` command of ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php), and I want to run this over +- 300 files and compare the actual sizes to expected sizes.

example output:

> $ identify rose.jpg
>
> rose.jpg JPEG 640x480 sRGB 87kb 0.050u 0:01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to run the `identify` command on all the jpg files in a directory and capture the output of that command into a text file for later comparison.  The comparison however is *not* part of the spec?

Something like the line below should do that job.  Just run it from the folder the jpg files are located:

```
for /R %%X in (*.jpg) do identify %%X >> PicInfo.txt
```

This will capture the `rose.jpg JPEG ...` line for every .jpg file you have in the directory (and subdirectories thanks to '/R') that you run the command in and append it to the file PicInfo.txt.

Comment: thx - I knew a few ways to do the comparison, hence not part of the question. I'm not very familiar with "for", so thx for that and I'll do some research on its various switches. As for ">>" that is actually the key to this - with it I guess the solution is easy, but I didn't know it existed (only knew about ">")

Comment: if you want, copy your answer to stackoverflow at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024848/compare-output-of-dos-command-to-something/15025467#15025467... I think it is a better answer than the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little hard to understand.  I’ll assume that you did something like

```
@echo off
for %%X in (*.jpg) do (
    identify "%%X" > "otherdir\%%X.id"
)
```

at some point in the past, thus creating files with names like `rose.jpg.id`, and now you want to verify that the JPEG files haven’t changed.  I suggest

```
@echo off
for %%X in (*.jpg) do (
    identify "%%X" > "tempdir\%%X.id.tmp"
    fc "tempdir\%%X.id.tmp" "otherdir\%%X.id" > nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo "tempdir\%%X.id.tmp" and "otherdir\%%X.id" differ.
    ) else (
        del "tempdir\%%X.id.tmp"
    )
)
```

`fc` is the Windows command line File Compare program.

Comment: +1 thx - answer given to mcalex because he answered forst, and for the ">>" append function.